# Data received from service is undefined in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am getting data back from a `json` file through an `injectable service` in Angular2. While consoling it in the service itself it shows the data. But when I get it back in my component through a call to the service, its showing as undefined.

Here's my **component**:

```
import {Component,OnInit} from "@angular/core"
import { DataService } from "./shared/data.service"
import { IData } from "./shared/data"

@Component({
    selector:"main-content",
    templateUrl:"src/app/main-content/main-content.component.html",
    styleUrls:['src/app/main-content/main-content.component.css']
})

export class MainComponent implements OnInit{

    data:IData;
    errorMessage:string;

    constructor(private _service:DataService){

    }


    ngOnInit():void{
        this._service.getData()
            .subscribe(data => this.data = data,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
        console.log(this.data);//this shows undefined on console
    }

}
```

**Service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { IData } from './data';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import "rxjs/Rx"

@Injectable()

export class DataService{
    private _dataUrl = 'Data/data.json';

    constructor(private _http:Http){}

    getData():Observable<IData>{
            return this._http.get(this._dataUrl)
            .map((res:Response) => <IData>res.json())
            .catch(this.handleError); 
      }

      private handleError(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }
}
```

**JSON:**

```
{
    "Client_ID":45645654,
    "Entity_Name":"Name of Entity",
    "Public_Interest_Entity":"No",
    "Industry_SIC":"Text Information",
    "Status_Client_Assessment":"In Progress",
    "Status_third_party_Assessment":"In Progress",
    "GIS_Details":{
        "GIS_ID":"GIS ID",
        "Global_Ut_Parent_ID":"Global Ut Parent ID",
        "KPMG_External_Audit_Client":"External Audit Client",
        "Direct_Parent_ID":"Direct Parent ID",
        "Global_Ut_DUNS_Number":"Global Ut DUNS Number",
        "GIS_Name":"GIS Name",
        "Global_Ultimate_Parent_Name":"Global Ultimate Parent Name",
        "Restricted_Entity_Status":"Restricted Entity Status",
        "Direct_Parent_Name":"Direct Parent Name"
    },
    "Client_Acceptance":{
        "Evaluation_ID":"Evaluation ID",
        "Client_Risk_Grade":"Client Risk Grade",
        "Evaluation_Type":"Evaluation Type",
        "Approved_on":"Approved on",
        "State":"State",
        "Created_on":"Created on",
        "Last_modified":"Last modified",
        "partner_lead":"partner lead",
        "Requester":"Requester"
    }
}
```

What is it that I am doing wrong? I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it has not happened yet, you receive the data in the call back and not immediately after you subscribe to the event.

```
ngOnInit():void{
    this._service.getData()
        .subscribe(data => {
           this.data = data;
           console.log(this.data);
      },
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);

}
```

Comment: I was first Igor :(

Comment: @Aravind - yes, by 6 seconds according to the post-time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But now when I try to print the `Client_ID` in json with `{{data.Client_ID}}`, it says `Cannot read property 'Client_ID' of undefined`.

Comment: @AakashThakur - more likely that `data` is (still) undefined. Use the `?` operator so that when the data is loaded it will materialize in the template. `{{data?.Client_ID}}`

Comment: Thanks again. It worked now. But what change did `?` bring? I have been previously outputting the data normally also.

Comment: @AakashThakur - It is called a [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator). When the template is evaluated the callback has not yet occurred so `data` is undefined. Using `?.` will ensure the evaluation on the expressions stops if the instance on the left is undefinied and proceed if it is not. This ensures you do not get an exception on an expression that is still waiting for a callback to occur.

Answer (score 3):

It takes time for your data to be received so it shows undefined. Placing it inside subscribe will be perfect

```
ngOnInit():void{
        this._service.getData()
            .subscribe(data => {
               this.data = data;
               console.log(this.data);//this works
        },
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);

}
```

Comment: I wonder how is my answer different from the above and posted before that. but still it is commented and marked as answer.